# obtener el id del ultimo insertado en Access?

Tags: c#, ms-access

Tengo el siguiente código que esta hecho para funcionar con una base de datos de `Mysql`:

```
public static long Insertar(MVentas objeto, facturacion.Vistas.VVentas form)
{
        long id = -1;
        MySqlConnection SqlCon = new MySqlConnection(Conexion.Cn);
        try
        {
            SqlCon.Open();
            string query001 = "INSERT INTO " + table + "(idCliente,idUsuario,fecVenta,montoTotal,montoLiteral,tipo,estado,numero) Values(@idCliente,@idUsuario,@fecVenta,@montoTotal,@montoLiteral,@tipo,@estado,@numero)";
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query001, SqlCon);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idCliente", objeto.idCliente);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idUsuario", objeto.idUsuario);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecVenta", objeto.fecVenta);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@montoTotal", objeto.montoTotal);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@montoLiteral", objeto.montoLiteral);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo", objeto.tipo);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@estado", objeto.estado);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numero", objeto.numero);

            if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
            {
                id=command.LastInsertedId;
                ToastNotification.Show(form, "venta Creada Correctamente", global::facturacion.Properties.Resources.ok, 3000, (eToastGlowColor.Green), (eToastPosition.TopRight));
                SqlCon.Close();
                return id;
            }
            else
            {
                ToastNotification.Show(form, "La venta no pudo ser Creada", global::facturacion.Properties.Resources.error, 3000, (eToastGlowColor.Red), (eToastPosition.TopRight));
                SqlCon.Close();
                return id;
            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException e)
        {
            ToastNotification.Show(form, e.Message, global::facturacion.Properties.Resources.error, 3000, (eToastGlowColor.Red), (eToastPosition.TopLeft));
            return id;
        }
    }
```

En dicho codigo tengo la linea `id=command.LastInsertedId;`: que es el id que debo de retornar per cuando hice el cambio este no funciona.

**Funcion cambiada para ACCESS**

```
public static long Insertar(MVentas objeto, facturacion.Vistas.VVentas form)
{
        long id = -1;
        OleDbConnection SqlCon = new OleDbConnection(Conexion.Cn);
        try
        {
            SqlCon.Open();
            string query001 = "INSERT INTO " + table + "(idCliente,idUsuario,fecVenta,montoTotal,montoLiteral,tipo,estado,numero) Values(@idCliente,@idUsuario,@fecVenta,@montoTotal,@montoLiteral,@tipo,@estado,@numero)";
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query001, SqlCon);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idCliente", objeto.idCliente);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idUsuario", objeto.idUsuario);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecVenta", objeto.fecVenta);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@montoTotal", objeto.montoTotal);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@montoLiteral", objeto.montoLiteral);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo", objeto.tipo);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@estado", objeto.estado);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numero", objeto.numero);

            if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
            {
                id=command.LastInsertedId;// me da error aqui
                ToastNotification.Show(form, "venta Creada Correctamente", global::facturacion.Properties.Resources.ok, 3000, (eToastGlowColor.Green), (eToastPosition.TopRight));
                SqlCon.Close();
                return id;
            }
            else
            {
                ToastNotification.Show(form, "La venta no pudo ser Creada", global::facturacion.Properties.Resources.error, 3000, (eToastGlowColor.Red), (eToastPosition.TopRight));
                SqlCon.Close();
                return id;
            }
        }
        catch (OleDbException e)
        {
            ToastNotification.Show(form, e.Message, global::facturacion.Properties.Resources.error, 3000, (eToastGlowColor.Red), (eToastPosition.TopLeft));
            return id;
        }
    }
```

> Entonces como cambio la linea código:`id=command.LastInsertedId;` por una funcional para `access`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Ms Access hay varias formas de hacerlo, pero recomiendo usar el `SCOPE_IDENTITY`
para obtenerlo uss el `ExecuteScalar()`

```
public static int Insertar(MVentas objeto, facturacion.Vistas.VVentas form)
{
    try
    {
        using(OleDbConnection SqlCon = new OleDbConnection(Conexion.Cn))
        {
            SqlCon.Open();
            string query001 = @"INSERT INTO Ventas (idCliente,idUsuario,fecVenta,montoTotal,montoLiteral,tipo,estado,numero) 
                                Values(@idCliente,@idUsuario,@fecVenta,@montoTotal,@montoLiteral,@tipo,@estado,@numero);
                                SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query001, SqlCon);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idCliente", objeto.idCliente);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idUsuario", objeto.idUsuario);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecVenta", objeto.fecVenta);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@montoTotal", objeto.montoTotal);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@montoLiteral", objeto.montoLiteral);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo", objeto.tipo);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@estado", objeto.estado);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numero", objeto.numero);

            return Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());

        }

    }
    catch (OleDbException e)
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

la idea es que si defines un metodo para insertar no pongas la notificacion dentro de este, sino que sea por fuera

```
int id = xx.Insertar(...);

if(id > 0)
{
    ToastNotification.Show(form, "venta Creada Correctamente", global::facturacion.Properties.Resources.ok, 3000, (eToastGlowColor.Green), (eToastPosition.TopRight));
}
else
{
    ToastNotification.Show(form, "La venta no pudo ser Creada", global::facturacion.Properties.Resources.error, 3000, (eToastGlowColor.Red), (eToastPosition.TopRight));
}
```

[Recuperar valores autonuméricos y de identidad](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-identity-or-autonumber-values)